# Android - Google map V2 : fix zoom to display first visible marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Pleas excuse my bad English, I'm French !

So, I've got a little question for my Android App.
I've to integrate a Google Map and display markers on the map.
Then, I've to dynamycaly zoom on user position.
It's ok for that.
BUT ! I want to fix the zoom in order to display the first visible marker.

For example : If there is a marker 3 km from here, the zoom will not be the same for a user who've got a marker 100meters from him !

Do you understand ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Do you have a list of LatLng for your markers?

Comment: did you tried LatLngBound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final LatLngBounds.Builder bc = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (LatLng marker : markers) {
    bc.include(marker);
}
bc.include(new LatLng(yourLat, yourLong));

map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bc.build(), padding));
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
    }
});
```

This will set correct zooming to fit the markers and your location, and then you can add some extra padding! Since the size has not been calculated, you will have to set `CameraChangeListener` to know when it has, then you can make the update and remove the listener.

Comment: Thanks ! But what is the "markers" variable ? How do you get markers ?

Comment: I've got this error : aused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map size should not be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.

Comment: Ok it works BUT it's not what I expected... I want to show the user position and the marker on the map ! (Just change the zoom param)